# document.querySelector() always return null when clicking on React Router Link the first time but will return correctly after

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-router-dom, selectors-api

I'm stucking on a problem with React-Router and querySelector.

I have a `Navbar` component which contains all the `CustomLink` components for navigation and a line animation which listens to those components and displays animation according to the current active component.

```
// Navbar.tsx

import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

import CustomLink from "./Link";

const Layout: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navbarRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [pos, setPos] = useState({ left: 0, width: 0 });

  const handleActiveLine = useCallback((): void => {
    if (navbarRef && navbarRef.current) {
      const activeNavbarLink = navbarRef.current.querySelector<HTMLElement>(
        ".tdp-navbar__item.active"
      );

      console.log(activeNavbarLink);

      if (activeNavbarLink) {
        setPos({
          left: activeNavbarLink.offsetLeft,
          width: activeNavbarLink.offsetWidth,
        });
      }
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleActiveLine();
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="tdp-navbar-content shadow">
        <div ref={navbarRef} className="tdp-navbar">
          <div className="tdp-navbar__left">
            <p>Todo+</p>
            <CustomLink to="/">About</CustomLink>
            <CustomLink to="/login">Login</CustomLink>
          </div>
          <div className="tdp-navbar__right">
            <button className="tdp-button tdp-button--primary tdp-button--border">
              <div className="tdp-button__content">
                <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
              </div>
            </button>
            <button className="tdp-button tdp-button--primary tdp-button--default">
              <div className="tdp-button__content">
                <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
              </div>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div
            className="tdp-navbar__line"
            style={{ left: pos.left, width: pos.width }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <main className="page">{children}</main>
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

```
// CustomLink.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

interface Props {
  to: string;
}

const CustomLink: React.FC<Props> = ({ to, children }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname === to) {
      setActive(true);
    } else {
      setActive(false);
    }
  }, [location, to]);

  return (
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/button-has-type
    <button
      className={`tdp-navbar__item ${active ? "active" : ""}`}
      onClick={(): void => {
        history.push(to);
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default CustomLink;
```

But it doesn't work as I want. So I opened Chrome Devtool and debugged, I realized that when I clicked on a  `CustomLink` first, the `querySelector()` from `Navbar` would return null. But if I clicked on the same `CustomLink` multiple times, it would return properly, like the screenshot below:

[Error from Chrome Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXLNh.png)

How can I get the correct return from `querySelector()` from the first time? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `handleActiveLine` will trigger before `setActive(true)` of `CustomLink.tsx`

Add a callback in `CustomLink.tsx`:

```jsx
const CustomLink: React.FC<Props> = ({ onActive }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    if (active) {
      onActive();
    }
  }, [active]);

}
```

In  `Navbar.tsx`:

```jsx
const Layout: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  
  function handleOnActive() {
     // do your query selector here
  }

  // add onActive={handleOnActive} to each CustomLink
  return <CustomLink onActive={handleOnActive} />
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. I'm gonna mark this answer